# Ошибка в коде бота для тг на python

Tags: python

Вот ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\goldn\porn.py", line 38, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\goldn\porn.py", line 28, in main
        updater = Updater(TOKEN)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    TypeError: Updater.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'
```

Вот код:

```
    import os
    import requests
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
    
    TOKEN = 'token'
    
    def start(bot, update):
        update.message.reply_text('Привет! Отправь мне ссылку на видео, чтобы я скачал его.')
    
    def downloadvideo(bot, update, args):
        chat_id = update.message.chat_id
        url = args[0]  # Получаем ссылку на видео из сообщения
        
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            filename = url.split('/')[-1]  # Извлекаем имя файла из ссылки
            with open(filename, 'wb') as videofile:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    if chunk:
                        videofile.write(chunk)
            update.message.reply_text('Видео успешно скачано!')
            bot.send_video(chat_id=chat_id, video=open(filename, 'rb'))
            os.remove(filename)  # Удаляем файл после отправки
        except Exception as e:
            update.message.reply_text('Произошла ошибка при скачивании видео.')
    
    def main():
        updater = Updater(TOKEN)
        dp = updater.dispatcher
    
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('download', downloadvideo, pass_args=True))
        
        updater.start_polling()
        updater.idle()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```